# How to change selectedIndex from a dropdown populated with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 dropdown lists that contains Regions,Locations,Sublocations of a country.
Im using Ajax to populate Locations And Sublocations lists after someone select something from first list.

**Now to my issue:**

Im using `LocalStorage` so when the page is refreshed i can keep the values and auto repopulate the lists with the last selected values.

The lists are sucessfuly populated but it fails to change the `selectedIndex`
("Select a Town/Select a Subloc" are selected).

I tried every single way i found in stackoverflow on how to change `selectedIndex` and none of them worked as also none of them threw me an error.
So i can assume there is an issue with `ajax` ? 
Something like js change the `selectedIndex` but `ajax` call rechange it back even if the `ajax` is called earlier than first.Could be something like that be possible ?

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 if(localStorage) {
  if(localStorage.regions) {
  jQuery('#region_h').val(localStorage.regions);
  alert(localStorage.regions);
  getlocations_main(localStorage.regions); //ajax call for locations
  }
  if(localStorage.locations) {
    jQuery('#location_h').val(localStorage.locations);
    jQuery('#location_h option').eq(this.selectedIndex).prop('selected',true);
    alert(localStorage.locations);
    getsublocations_main(localStorage.locations); //ajax call for subloc
  }
  if(localStorage.subloc){
    jQuery('#subloc_h option').eq(this.selectedIndex).prop('selected',true);
  }

}
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row rowInput_spiti360">
 <div class="ie_fix_select_spiti360" >
  <div id="location_add_yo" class="mainselection" >
   <select class=" searchcategory" name="location_h" id="location_h" onchange="getsublocations_main(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select a Town:</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>  

<div class="row rowInput_spiti360">
 <div class="ie_fix_select_spiti360" >
  <div id="sublocation_add_yo"  class="mainselection" >
   <select id="subloc"  name="subloc" class=" searchcategory">
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select a sublocation:</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you prepare a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: What do you get for `this.selectedIndex`? It seems to me `this` is referring to  `window` rather than html element.

Comment: `this` in the context you are using is supposed to represent the document. I think this.selectedIndex should be undefined.

Comment: @Arvind Oh god im so retarded. It was indeed referring to window element. Changed that and now it works. Place it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `this.selectedIndex`, here `this` is referring to `window` rather than html element

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - look more closely. It was and is. At the request of the OP it was posted as an answer too.